# Automatically Click Mouse at Random location using pynput (for a web browser game)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, bots, pynput

**Info.**

Hey there :)
I'm learning Python for a few weeks now, and I just started with some small projects. Now I'm building a script to automate an webbrowser game. The script sends out a few "expeditions" which give me more rescources inside the game. The script is already working but i would like to improve it. If you have any tips i would love to hear them.

**Question.**
**I'm using pynput and mouse.position = () for an exact location to click. Is there a way to make the click random inside a certain area?** Because normal person woudn't always click in the same location.

like click at a random location between these positions:
mouse.position (2000, 500)
mouse.position (3000, 1000)

**My script.**

```
import pynput, time, random, sys
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
timeDelay = random.randrange(2, 4)


def locateogame():
    #---------------------------------------------> Getting to Ogame.nl
    mouse = MouseController()
    keyboard = KeyboardController()
    mouse.position = (2392, 48)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    keyboard.type("Ogame.nl")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    #login to account and universe.
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2343, 564)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def p1():
    #---------------------------------------------> Locate to planet 1
    mouse = MouseController()
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (3054, 298)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def p2():
   #---------------------------------------------> Locate to planet 2
    #Locate to 5:352:8
    mouse = MouseController()
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (3060, 382)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def p3():
    #---------------------------------------------> Locate to planet 3
    #Locate to 5:353:7 
    mouse = MouseController()
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (3074, 438)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def p4():
    #---------------------------------------------> Locate to planet 4
    #Locate to 5:353:8 
    mouse = MouseController()
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (3073, 481)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def p5():
    #---------------------------------------------> Locate to planet 5
    #Locate to 4:32:8 
    mouse = MouseController()
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (3099, 538)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def Sending():
#---------------------------------------------> This will do all the clicking to send my ships
    mouse = MouseController()
    keyboard = KeyboardController()
    #Select Fleet from menu
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2254, 493)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    #select "Expeditie" Fleet
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2670, 694)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    #Expedition
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2598, 743)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2954, 678)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    #select slot 16
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2796, 434)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    keyboard.type("16")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    #expeditie button
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2408, 378)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    #send Fleet
    time.sleep(timeDelay)
    mouse.position = (2862, 711)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)


##---------------------------------------------> Start of the script.
locateogame()

fns = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]
from random import choice
choice(fns)()

Sending()
```

Thanks for your time and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to sample a value from a range. Just do this twice, once for your X value and again for Y

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(2000, 3000)
2786
>>> random.randint(500, 1000)
838
```

So in your code you could do

```
from random import randint
mouse.position = (randint(2000, 3000), randint(500, 1000))
```